# Compilation errors with AoT and external JS dependencies

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I am getting the following error

> "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'quickstartLib'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 22:15 in the original .ts file), resolving s ymbol AppModule" while doing AoT compile."

I included `quickstartLib.umd.js` using script tag in `index.html` and used it in `app.module.ts` using  `"declare var quickstartLib:any;"` Any suggestions would help

Comment: can you try putting it in `angular-cli.json` file under `scripts` array and then try, if you are using cli

Comment: I am using webpack

Comment: https://github.com/swingmicro/AngularLazyLoad.git

Comment: above is the github repo of my application